# How to scaffold Database in ASP.NET Core using Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have tried using the following command ( which works fine if I use Visual Studio) :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=12.345.567.890;Database=ABC;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=xyz;Password=12345;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f
```

While trying the above command using Visual Studio code terminal, I get this error:

> The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
>   again

Comment: Did you install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package ?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to install something in Visual Studio Code editor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may have to run the **command line version** of scaffolding. The command you have posted is for the Package Manager in Visual Studio

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=12.345.567.890;Database=ABC;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=xyz;Password=12345;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

Source
[ASP.NET Core - Write Apps with Visual Studio Code and Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt767698.aspx)